# ListView with scrollable horizontal rows

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, horizontal-scrolling

Working on a `ListView` with a custom list view adepter inherited from `BaseAdapter`. I'm trying to implement a table style in which each row is horizontally scrollable. Therefore, I'm using `HorizontalScrollView` and `LinearLayout` to structure each row. In each row, there are multiple `TextView` with hardcoded texts in each. Everything is happening in the code and there's no xml and layout file. The issue that I'm having is I don't see any of `TextView` items that I add to my `LinearLayout`. Those `TextView` are added as a child view to `LinearLayout` and inside `onLayout` method on set up their layout as:

```
int dx = 0, viewWidth = 180;
for (int i = 0; i < m_Views.length; i++) {

TextView view = m_Views[i];

int textViewWidth = viewWidth;
if (i == 0) {
    textViewWidth *= 2;
}

view.layout(dx, 0, dx + textViewWidth, contentHeight);

dx += textViewWidth;
}
m_HorizontalScrollView.layout(0, 0, contentWidth, contentHeight);
m_LinearLayout.layout(0, 0, dx, contentHeight);
```

That code, doesn't render `TextView` elements. In addition, if I try to add the following line before setting the view's layout:

```
view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
```

The app crashes with the following error in `LinearLayout.java` class, `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array`.

I'm curious to know:

1. Why the layout of text views don't change with calling `layout` method?
2. Why does the app crashes if I call `measure` method?

PS: Using `RecyclerView` or any other approaches that requires in changing the adepter and list view is out of scope since that requires changing in the framework and base classes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling `layout` or `measure` direction on a view.  Rather, you should set the `LayoutParams` of the view using `View.setLayoutParams()`. Since you are using a LinearLayout, you would use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` as your concrete implementation.  Remove all direct calls to `layout` and `measure` and let the Android layout system handle this.

Comment: Have tried that, and it didn't work. I believe the issue would be because of all parents and other views are layout in `onLayout` method, that kinda doesn't work. My issue here is why `TextView` doesn't accept the layout changes that I set

Comment: The reason the layout changes are not being accepted is because you are not updating your widget properly  The issue is the Android layout system will call `layout()` on its own, with the properties from the `LayoutParams` before the view is displayed, effectively overruling your call to `layout()`.  That is just the way Android works.  I don't know why updating the `LayoutParams` is not working for you, I would need to see more code, but the way you are trying to do things will never work.  It goes completely against the way the Android layout system works.

Comment: Just a continuation of my previous message.  The View methods `layout()` and `measure` are not meant to be called directly during view creation.  They are called during the UI system's layout pass.  The only reason to ever use these methods is if you need to override them in a `View` subclass because for some reason the default Android layout and/or measuring do not work for your use case.  Just to give you an idea of how often this is needed, I am one of the maintainers of an Android app with over 100 views, and we never do this even once.

Comment: Finally, if you are having issues with Android layout in code, I would suggest creating your view in XML and then inflating it in code.  It will make your life a lot easier than doing layout in code.

Comment: Thanks for in-detail explanation. Unfortunately, there's nothing that I can do about the way it is laying out the UI. I could find a workaround and skip using measure